# How to import csv file to datagridview column by column

Tags: excel, vb.net, csv, datagridview, import

Good day, i'm having conflict while importing csv file to my datagridview.

Here's my code:

```
Try
        Dim conn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim ds As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim comm As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim path As String = filepath

        conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + "; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';")
        comm = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [WSC2017_TP09_M2_Schedules_V12_a$]", conn)

        ds = New System.Data.DataSet
        comm.Fill(ds)
        Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

When i import the file ot goes here:
[image: It goes here.]

That supposed to be here:
[image: Supposed to be here]

when i import the file the data goes indent nd the origigal data in datagridview chaange by the content of the csv file.

This is the csv file:
[image: Csv file]

Comment: Can you give an example of your CSV? Does it start with `,,something`?

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly?  The problem is that it's appearing in Form1.Datagridview1 when it should appear in ApplyScheduleChanges.Datagridview1?

If so, that's because of this line `Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)`

Surely you mean `ApplyScheduleChanges.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)`

Comment: @Vityata it is staarting with add, 12-01-1998,6:25,75, AUH,RUH,1,983,OK

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom thnk u for response. Im not having problem with form. When im importing csv the data goes indent.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood.

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom as u can see on the pic the first pic where it has column header that should be the place of data but it goes 'second pic' where the data create its own column

Comment: Help me this is so important for me :(

Comment: You probably have some columns in which the DataPropertyName is already set and the field names coming from you DataSource don't match.

Comment: How will i solve it?

Comment: You need to explain - and even understand - the problem(s) better.  "data goes indent" is vague and not even accurate: it appears to be skipping your premade columns.  The first thing I see is that there are more desired columns than there are columns in the CSV. The best thing to do would be to use a SCHEMA.INI so you can name and type your columns.  You could also just rename the columns after they are imported